# Showing user-specific 'Limited' albums in Picasa Web Albums on my own site

Tags: php, oauth, wordpress, google-api, picasa

I need help finding out how to list my albums from [Picasa Web Albums](http://picasaweb.google.com) on my WordPress site.

My [Album Feed](https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/lobner) shows all my albums when I am logged in, and only the 'Public' ones, when not. And, more importantly, when one of my allowed viewers are logged in, they can see only what I have allowed them to. ([Album visibility](http://picasa.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=39551))

There exists several fancy solutions. Ie. [PWA+PHP](http://code.google.com/p/pwaplusphp/) for WordPress. But common for the ones I have been able to find, are that they option only to show the 'Public' (default) or ***all*** the albums. Thus disregarding my 'Limited' list. (ie. email-addresses / Google+ Circles)

Creating a WebApp with access to my albums is thus not a solution, since I wish to give users individual access. Just like if they visited my [Picasa site](http://picasaweb.google.com/lobner).

Are there suggestions to ways to achieve something like this?

Comment: I'm also looking for something like that but have not found it yet :S

Comment: Neither have I. And it does not seem like anybody else have knowledge of such either...?

Comment: I am working on a jQuery script that takes parameters for the Picasa web album name, tags to search within the album, max results, height and width. Does any of that sound like what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest the [Pimax plugin](http://www.codehandling.com/2015/03/pimax-20-embed-google-plus-picasa-album.html) in this case. It will get you very close to your requirement.

**What it does -**

First of all it will show all you public photos in a Tab. All your public albums in another Tab. (Since you do not want to display all public stuff, you can hide these two Tabs)

**How it will address your requirement -**

Next if you want to display some specific albums or any featured albums, you can specify the link to those albums. Photos from each of those Albums will be displayed in a separate Tab.

Now, if you want to display all you public Albums except few albums, you can specify those exceptions. Your Albums Tab will now display all public albums except the ones that you wanted to exclude!

Hope this solves the problem of anyone with similar requirement :)